# Nginx not redirecting server error to custom page

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I configured Nginx in docker to redirect error 500 to a custom page (500.php) but this error is not being redirected to my custom page. Could you please assist?

Below is my configurations in .docker/conf/nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/;


    location / {
        error_page 500 = /500.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) directive in the nginx config:
*Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal to 300 should be passed to a client or be intercepted and redirected to nginx for processing with the [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive.*

```
server {
    [...]
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 500 = http://example.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.org;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your configuration file to this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /error_50x.html;
    location = /error_50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            internal;
    }

}
```

Please put the error_50x.html in the /usr/share/nginx/html path. Restart the nginx server. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a rough idea about ngnix config

```
server {    
    listen 80;  
    server_name host.docker.internal;   

    # By default land on localhost:80 to root so in root we copied UI build to the ngnix html dir.
    # have a look to docker-compose uiapp service.
    location / {    
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;   
            index  index.html index.htm;    
    }   

   # after location add filter, from which every endpoint starts with or comes in endpoint 
   # so that ngnix can capture the URL and reroute it.
   # like /backend/getUserInfo/<UserId> 
   # In above example /backend is that filter which will be captured by Ngnix and reroute the flow.
    location /backend { 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;    
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;  
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #proxy_pass http://<ContainerName>:<PortNumber>; 
        # In our case Container name is as we setup in docker-compose `beservice` and port 8080
        proxy_pass http://beservice:8080;   
    }   
}
```

This could help you to write your own.

For more details, you have a look at this project

https://github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv

This can help you to understand how to how this all routing works

Comment: I run this example and I received forbidden - directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.32.1, server: 192.168.100.8, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.100.8". =(